# Javascript D3 nested lambda function confusion

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lambda

I've got this snippet that I don't understand.

```
var data = [3, 2, 4, 1];

window.onload = async function() {
    d3.select( '#canvas' )
        .selectAll( 'rect' )
        .data( data )
        .join(
            enter => {
                enter.append( 'rect' )
                    .attr( 'x', d => d*50 )
                    .attr( 'width', 20 )
                    .attr( 'height', d=> d*50 )
                    .attr( 'y', 20 )
                    .attr( 'id', d => 'rect' + d )
                    .style( 'fill', 'blue' );
            });
        }
```

I understand that we're selecting the canvas and creating a rect for each datapoint. I believe we're passing a function into selection.join() that is used to join the rectangle to the data.

How and what is the 'enter' that being passed into the function passed into join? Also, how and what is the 'd' that is being passed into the other nested lambda functions?

Comment: Those are just arguments of functions. The names are arbitrary. Read more about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Just as a complement to the accepted answer and the comment above, the names of the parameters are arbitrary. That `attr()` method passes 3 arguments to its second parameter (provided it's a function), which are the datum, the index and the nodes collection. Hence, in D3 we normally use `d` for datum, `i` for index and `n` for nodes, for instance `(d, i, n) => etc...`. But again you can use anything you want (if valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join()` has three parameters, each of which is a function that handles entering, updating and exiting elements.

Your function has a single parameter (by convention named enter) which is a selection of entering elements. You could also write it with normal syntax an not arrow function.

example:

```
join(
    function(enter) {
      ...
    },
    function(update) {
      ...
    },
    function(exit) {
      ...
    }
)
```

To update an attribute, you use `attr()`. This function takes two parameters:

- **Attribute Name** - For example, "height" to set the height of the SVG.
- **Value or An accessor function.** - For example "10" to set the height to 10 or an accessor function that sets the value per data point based on the data (by conventioned named d).

This anccessor function can have 2 more params. Like:

```
attr('fill', (d,i,nodes) => ...)
```

- the index of the current item (by convention i), and
- the group of nodes in the selection

Comment: So select.join is expecting 1-3 functions that would each have one parameter in them, which select.join will then call with the parameter entered in data?

Comment: Something like that. You can read more here https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#selection_join